# firefox addOn-SDK: is it possible to open a modal external dialog window?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I use that in my FF addonSDK to open a new external window popup.

```
win = require('sdk/window/utils').openDialog({
    features: Object.keys({
        centerscreen: true,
        resizable: true,
        scrollbars: true
    }).join() + ',width='+w+',height='+h+',top='+pos.top+',left='+pos.left,
    name: "mysite"

});
```

Works fine except it reacts as a simple popup window.
I wish it could be a modal panel window (similar to chrome panel).

Can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. you need to use "sdk/panel" high level API.
refer to this link for more examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel